# How do you position a set of buttons that don't move when text size changes?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, button, position

I'm stuck on trying to make these buttons positions absolute so that when the counter text doesn't mess up the positioning of the buttons. Here's the source code and image of what I'm talking about:

```
render() {
    let classes = this.getBadgeClasses();
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div>
                <span
                    style={this.styles}
                    className={classes}
                >
                    {this.formatCount()}

                </span>
                <button
                    onClick={() => this.props.onIncrement(this.props.counter)}
                    className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm m-2"
                >
                    +
                </button>
                <button
                    onClick={() => this.props.onDecrement(this.props.counter)}
                    className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm m-2"
                >
                    -
                </button>
                <button
                    onClick={() => this.props.onDelete(this.props.counter.id)}
                    className="btn btn-danger btn-sm m-2"
                >
                    x
                </button>
            </div>
            <div>
                {this.state.tags.length === 0 && 'Please create a new tag!'}
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

[image: issue]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to give a specific width to the span element

Comment: So make a span for each button and wrap all of the buttons with one span?